# ng-modal in ng-repeat issue

Tags: angularjs

Below is my code, I have 3 inputs and a view button where upon clicking view I will be getting data from server.
3 inputs are Customer, Date, Shift and I'm keeping this 3 inputs in a ng-repeat where it repeats for number of customers I have. If customerID = 1 then the ng-model for customer input is also 1.

```html
<div ng-repeat = "x in CustomerList">
      <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="getproductiondetails()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
                                <select required class="form-control" ng-value= "x.customerID"  ng-model="data.CustomerID">
                                   
                                </select> 
                            </div>
                        
                       
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" ng-model="data.ProductionReportDate" is-open="popup1.opened" required close-text="Close" />
                            </div>
                        
                        
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-mars"></i></span>
                                <select required class="form-control" ng-model="data.ShiftTypeID">
                                    <option value="">Shift</option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="y in shiftList" value="{{y.ShiftTypeID}}">{{y.ShiftTypeName}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 pull-left">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

But here for ng-model in customer input it is not selecting upon the value of customerID.
How to make customer input to select customerID value from ng-repeat?

Sample Data in CustomerList:

1. CustomerID = 1, CustomerName = KL
2. CustomerID = 2, CustomerName = JK

Sample Data in ShiftList:

1. ShiftID = 1, ShiftName = 1st Shift
2. ShiftID = 2, ShiftName = 2nd Shift

Comment: Sorry It's Angular

Comment: Maybe it should be `ng-model="x.ShiftTypeID"` instead of `ng-model="data.ShiftTypeID"`? And you should avoid the same repeater alias name (`ng-repeat="x in shiftList"` in the options and `ng-repeat = "x in CustomerList"`(

Comment: For starters `ng-repeat="x in CustomerList"` and `ng-repeat="x in shiftList"` share the variable `x` which it probably doesn't like.

Comment: The problem is in 1st input (customer).

Comment: @Ranger Please include a sample of the data inside `CustomerList` and `shiftList`

Comment: Customer dropdown could likely be broken because of the reason given above if `x` is being redefined/overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Should you repeat on a form? Could you not repeat and display values instead? 
On every row you could have an edit button. Pressing that button could enter edit mode. I like to divide view mode and edit mode. NOTE: if you want to edit one row at the time you will need to have a server PUT/PATCH resource for a 'SINGLE' row object. Please reply if you want a simple example